# .apply vs. .replace in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm self-learning Pandas and Python and am trying to figure out how to replace a column full of integers with strings. Say I have a dataset full of ages, and I want to group them into categories in a new column.
Age < 30, replace with string 'young'
Ages between 30 and 50, replace with 'middle aged'
Ages > 50 , replace with 'older'

What's the easiest way to do this?

I've looked into what .apply and .replace do with dataframes, but I'm getting confused. Am I supposed to be learning what 'lambda' is? Should I be defining a function and then using the .apply function, or is there a simpler way? Thanks so much.

```
1 62
2 47
3 34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to determine the age:

```
def check(age):
    if age > 50:
        return 'Old'
    elif 30 <= age <= 50:
        return 'Middle'
    else:
        return 'Young'
```

Then use **apply()** to encode all data.

```
res = df.apply(check)
```

Result:

```
0    62
1    47
2    34

0       Old
1    Middle
2    Middle
```

Comment: you have only addressed apply() and failing to address .replace()

Answer (score 0):

could just alter the df directly too..

```
df.loc[(df['age']<30),'age']='young'
df.loc[(df['age']>=30) & (df['age']<=50),'age']='middle'
df.loc[(df['age']>50),'age']='old'
```